# Scrapy pagination uses javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pagination, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a 3-level site I want to crawl and parse the links from the levels 2 and 3. The problem is that in the 2nd level there is a javascript pagination which provides different links for every page (5 pages total).

Example:
Level 1: Main menu (I extract the links of the categories using SgmlLinkExtractor catid=22767)
Level 2: There are links that I want to parse, but there is javascript pagination also from where I need to extract the rest of the links (i.e. catid=22767&page1=2)
Level 3: For each link of the above step I want to parse the response.

The site is (http://www.ethnos.gr/)
The level2 is (summary.asp?catid=22768)
The level3 is an article page which I want to parse (article.asp?catid=22768&subid=2&pubid=63929343)

The question is: For every extracted link from the 1st level, how can I create a loop and construct all 5 links and then use the SgmlLinkExtractor in the 2nd level to follow those links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to this:

1. Commonly web sites provide a crawlable version of their site or you can implement a [sitemap](http://boxesandarrows.com/sitemaps-and-site-indexes-what-they-are-and-why-you-should-have-them/).
2. You can use something like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which renders the page in your browser so JavaScript is enabled and you can use it like a user would and still scrape it.

Make sure you do the scraping in a [ethical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Politeness_policy) way as not to overload the site :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately the site does not provide a sitemap. Basically my question is how to feed SgmlLinkExtractor with constructed (custom) urls instead of the start_url. Maybe there is a way to override the start_requests function but I don't know how to parse the response inside.

Comment: @axs203dd hmm you might want to provide an example of what you'd like in code or have tried to get a better answer.  What you have is a bit high level.